# What is the best way to validate a foreign key association in Rails belongs to current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

As an example, say I have a credit card that belongs to a user with an associated billing address.

One solution is that I assign the relationship in the create/update block. However, this really requires me to handle the errors such as blank id or non-existing record. Was hoping there was a better solution that i have overlooked.

I am interested in making sure that an address that belongs to another user is not assigned to the current user.

So, code for the create solution:

```
credit_card = current_user.credit_cards.create!(credit_card_params) do |credit_card|
    credit_card.address  = User.addresses.find(params['credit_card']['address_id'])
end
```

I haven't added the error handling yet and could push that to a class method in the User object and then call User.set_address('address_id') which also handles validation. Is there a better pattern for doing this?

Comment: Please post your model User, Address and Credit Card. It is hard do say with so little info but it seems that you should validate the uniqueness on the Address isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at it from the credit card point of view, you just want to make sure that the `address_id` is unique, meaning the `address_id` can't be used twice on two different credit cards.

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :address_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

If a new credit card is initialized with an `address_id` that belongs to another user the credit card becomes invalid.

Update: by adding a scope to the uniqueness validation, you allow duplication for a smaller set, which in your case would be the `user_id` ( if 2 creditcards have the same address, and the same user then that's fine )

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :address_id, uniqueness: { scope: user_id }
end
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work in the situation where I may have multiple credit cards with the same billing address.